# iOS: does Google Mobile Ads automatically handle AdSupport requirements?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have developed an iOS app that uses the Google Mobile Ads framework to display a single banner ad through AdMob:

```
var bannerView: GADBannerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ID"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}
```

A quick `grep` tells me this framework makes use of the AdSupport framework: both `advertisingIdentifier` and `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled`.

From the Google Mobile Ads SDK download page:

> The Mobile Ads SDK for iOS utilizes Apple's advertising identifier (IDFA). The SDK uses IDFA under the guidelines laid out in the iOS developer program license agreement. You must ensure you are in compliance with the iOS developer program license agreement policies governing the use of this identifier.

This suggests that the Google Mobile Ads framework automatically deals with these flags in compliance with Apple's guidelines (provided you don't add code that modifies them, which I have not).

I want to ensure that my app is in compliance with guidelines before submission. Is the way the Google Mobile Ads framework deals with these flags acceptable as-is, or will I have to add code to handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. The above default banner is acceptable and the app was approved for the App Store.